# If $a_n\to+\infty$, $b_n\to0$, how about $\prod_{k=1}^n(1+b_ne^{-a_k})$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits, infinite-product

If $a_n$ and $b_n$ are real series, and $a_n\to+\infty$, $b_n\to0$, how is the limit
$$\underset{n\to\infty}{\lim}\prod_{k=1}^n(1+b_ne^{-a_k})?$$

There could be some specific requirements on $a_n$ and $b_n$, but I wish a more general result. Thanks~

Thanks for all the answers below, but I think I need a restriction like this:
$$a_n\sim C_1n^{\alpha},\qquad b_n\sim C_2n^{-\beta},$$
where $C_1,C_2,\alpha,\beta$ are constants, and $\alpha$, $\beta$ are positive.

I really need this problem to be solved, hope someone can help, thanks~

Comment: The tag ([tag:limit-theorems]) is intended for questions about limit theorems in probability theory and not for questions about determining limits of sequences or functions, see the [tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/limit-theorems/info) and the tag-excerpt. (The tag-excerpt is also shown when you are adding a tag to a question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $b_n$ is sufficiently small, more precisely $1+b_ie^{-a_J}>0,$ we can take the logarithm and use the asymptotic $\ln (1+x)\asymp x.$ The convergence of the product is equivalent to the convergence of $c_n=b_n\sum_{k=1}^ne^{-a_k}.$ Obviously, $c_n$ does not usually converge. One may take $b_n=\frac{1}{\ln \ln{n}}$ and $a_k=\ln k.$ However, for some particular sequences one may get the results about convergence. For instance, if $b_n\asymp \frac{1}{n}$ then $c_n=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^ne^{-a_k}}{n}\to 0$ by Cesàro mean theorem.

Edit (continuation for an updated question).

Using the conditions you mentioned above $c_n$ can be rewritten as 
$$c_n\asymp n^{-\beta}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n a^{n^{\alpha}}\right),$$
where $a=e^{-C_1}.$ Now we apply Stoltz- Cesaro theorem to compute the limit:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}c_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\left(\sum_{k=1}^n a^{n^{\alpha}}\right)}{n^{\beta}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a^{(n+1)^{\alpha}}}{(n+1)^{\beta}-n^{\beta}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a^{(n+1)^{\alpha}}}{\beta n^{\beta-1}}.$$
You can now easily analyze convergence of the last limit depending on the values of $\alpha,\beta$ and $a.$

Comment: $a_n$ tends to infinity in the problem statement so your first supposition doesn't work.

Comment: $a_n=\ln n$ which does tend to infinity. So I can see no problem. Of course, we just need $b_n$ to be small, thanks. I have edited the post.

Comment: Could you please explain more about the asymptotic $\ln(1+x)\sim x$? For a single term it works, but for the whole sum it doesn't work in general. Thanks!~

Comment: It does work. In order to see that, note that you have bounds $x-\frac{x^2}{2}\le \ln (1+x)\le x.$ So for $0\le a_k\to 0$ the sum $\sum a_k$ converges if and only if so does $\sum a_k-\frac{a_k^2}{2}$ and thus we have bounds for our sum from above and from below.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, thank you~

Answer (score 2):

Take $b_n = 0$, then the limit is equal to $1$.

Take $a_n = \log(\sqrt{n})$ and $b_n = \log^{-1}(n)$, then the limit is now $\infty$.

Thus, no general result exists.